# Spark read Parquet files of different versions

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, versions

I have parquet files generated for over a year with a Version1 schema. And with a recent schema change the newer parquet files have Version2 schema extra columns.

So when i load parquet files from the old version and new version together and try to filter on the changed columns i get an exception.

I would like for spark to read old and new files and fill in null values where the column is not present.Is there a workaround for this where spark fills null values when the column is not found?

Answer (score 1):

SparkSQL itself support schema merging for parquet files. You can read all about it in [official documentation here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging)

> Like ProtocolBuffer, Avro, and Thrift, Parquet also supports schema
>   evolution. Users can start with a simple schema, and gradually add
>   more columns to the schema as needed. In this way, users may end up
>   with multiple Parquet files with different but mutually compatible
>   schemas. The Parquet data source is now able to automatically detect
>   this case and merge schemas of all these files.
>
> Since schema merging is a relatively expensive operation, and is not a
>   necessity in most cases, we turned it off by default starting from
>   1.5.0. You may enable it by

1. > setting data source option mergeSchema to true when reading Parquet
   >   files (as shown in the examples below), or
2. > setting the global SQL option spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema to true.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways you may have a try.

1.like this way that you can use a map transform,but this not recommended,such as `spark.read.parquet("mypath").map(e => val field =if (e.isNullAt(e.fieldIndex("field"))) null else e.getAs[String]("field"))`

2.the best way that you can use mergeSchema option,such as :

```
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(xxx).as[MyClass]
```

ref:[schema-merging](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a set of files you intend to read:

1. Query the schema of each file in the set producing N sets of files, each set containing files with similar schemas.
2. Operate on each set of files using a filter compatible with the schema in each set.
3. Union the results of filtering/operating on each set (assuming your output is the same for results from each file schema)