# Pyspark Merge Schema Option with Parquet Files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Merging schema across multiple parquet files in Spark works great. However, it introduces Nulls for non-existing columns in the associated files, post merge, and I understand the reason for the same.
However, I was wondering if there is a way to define a default value (user-defined) instead of Spark assigning Nulls.

So, today:

```
file1   col1    col2            
file2   col1    col2    col3    col4    
                    
merge file1 and file2, using option - "mergeSchema", "true" col1    col1    col2    col3    col4
file1 contents                                              X       X       Null    Null    Null
file2 contents                                              X       X       X       X       X
```

I was wondering whether we could do something like this:

```
file1   col1    col2            
file2   col1    col2    col3    col4    
                    
merge file1 and file2, using option - "mergeSchema", "true" col1    col1    col2    col3    col4
file1 contents                                              X       X       -999    -999    -999
file2 contents                                              X       X       X       X       X
```

This will help a lot in terms of identifying true nulls post merge.

I searched through the posts and documentation; however, couldn't find much related. Any pointers or thoughts around this will be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489842/spark-choose-default-value-for-mergeschema-fields

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and I did consider a similar approach. This solution handles the situation by opening each and every parquet file and adding the missing columns manually. That's one way; however, might not be an efficient approach when merging the schema for a large number of files (possibly 100s of thousands or more). Hence, was wondering whether there is an alternate way without opening each and every parquet file.

Comment: I am looking at this 2 lines. "You don't have any simple method to put a default value when column doesn't exist in some parquet files but exists in other parquet files".   If you own the creation of these files, you could insert the default value at the creation, but otherwise, I think you need to hack around.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately inserting default values during creation is not a good design alternative for my process. I'll try out a hack and update if I find an optimal solution.